# MVC - Variable in .cshtml file which updates the html when the controller calls it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

this is probably a pretty basic thing for you guys, but I still can't figure it out. 
Let's say I have a View:

myView.cshtml

```
<div>
    <p>Some content here</p>
    @MyHTMLVariable //Calls updateHTML -> MyHTMLVariable = s
    <p>Some more content over here</p>
</div>
```

myController.cs

```
public string updateHTML() 
{
 s = "I'm a string"; //Changes dynamically, handled by different stuff outside
 //Any string to html-conversion needen?
 return s;
}
```

How can I "update" the variable in the view / how do I have to initialize it?

Cheers,

DDerTyp

Comment: how are you calling updateHTML? through ajax..

Comment: Yep, exactly. But how do I place/initialize the Variable in myView.cshtml? Maybe that was unclear, sorry.
- To make it even more clear, can someone give me the sourcecode for the myView.cshtml file? What do I have to write betweenthe <p>-tags?

Comment: No you cannot do that. Server side variables are render as their values in view..

Comment: You can intiallize `@{ var MyHTMLVar = "" }` in this way

Comment: Okay, thank you @mmushtaq =)
If it is not possible the way I want, could I store the source code of myView in a string, insert the MyHTMLVariable at the specific location (in the string) and write the "new" source code in the myView.cshtml?

Comment: What is your requirement/scenario to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to update your variable value?

Comment: The user inputs some stuff in a form. I do some stuff with the input and need to display the result. Sounds easy, huh? But I need to save the new created HTML-Elements inside the view (not in a modal), they have to be in the view so that the elements even exists, after the user has refreshed the page.

Comment: You don't update server side variables on client side. Not possible. Can't you store whatever data you want in a `data-*` html5 attribute or use `@Html.Hidden("MyDataName", serverValue)` helper to render a hidden input on the page and then update this value dynamically with ajax? I can post example if this is in the right direction.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a partial view with a corresponding ajax method on your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Razor's @functions code block to declare your functions within your view this way...

```
@functions {
    public string updateHtml() 
    {
        string s = "I'm a string";/*or whatever dynamic stuff you wanna do*/
        return s;
    }
}

@{
    string myHtmlVariable = updateHtml();
}
```

Then use @myHtmlVariable within your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ViewBag for this.  In your template use `@ViewBag["MyHTMLVaribale"]` and in your controller method use `ViewBag["MyHTMLVariable"] = "I'm a string";`